# Error with Swift Code: String.Type does not have a member named 'stringWithContentOfURL'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6-beta6

I have some code that worked properly before the latest update, After updating to the latest version of Xcode I am getting this error

> String.Type does not have a member named 'stringWithContentOfURL'

The code is below.

```
func searchFlickrForString(searchStr:String, completion:(searchString:String!, flickrPhotos:NSMutableArray!, error:NSError!)->()){
   let searchURL:String = FlickrHelper.URLForSearchString(searchStr)
   let queue:dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

    dispatch_async(queue, {

        var error:NSError?

        let searchResultString:String! = String.stringWithContentsOfURL(NSURL.URLWithString(searchURL), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)

        if error != nil{
            completion(searchString: searchStr, flickrPhotos: nil, error: error)
        }
```

Comment: The code you provided is incomplete. What is `FlickrHelper`? Where are the closing brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factory methods have pretty much all been replaced by Swift initializers (this happened quite a while ago, if I remember correctly). The ones you want are:

```
let searchResultString:String! = String(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: searchURL)!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
```

Note that `NSURL(string:)` returns an optional `NSURL` - handle it however you think best.